# SAML Authentication without using SAML Authorization

Tags: c#, saml-2.0

I have been asked to implement integration with a SAML 2.0 IdP for user Authentication purposes.  I have never worked with any federated authorization processes so this is all new to me so please forgive if I am asking a stupid question but here it goes.

For My needs all I want is to send a SAMLP Authentication request.  If I get a response that says the user is valid I will give them access to my system which will have a user id that matches what is returned.  From that point on all authorization is to be performed by my system and I do not need to send a token with each request to the SAML IdP. After they log in I am done with the IdP.

Many of the questions and examples I see on here and other sites include adding extensive libraries to my project.  When I look at them and the documentation around them they all seem to want to either perform the authentication with every request through an IIS Module or through integration with the MVC routing mechanism.

So now to my question.  Can't I just create the XML myself and stick it on the the querystring as the SAMLRequest value?  Then parse the response XML that comes back for the values I need?  If this is a valid way of doing it does anyone have some example code that does this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow that you describe is how things are normally done: One SAML2 request to the Idp to authenticate the user, and then setting a session cookie for all subsequent requests.

Don't create this yourself unless you want to investigate substantial time to understand SAML2 and XML signature validation rules. They are **complex** and most custom implementations get it wrong, resulting in compromised security.

My own library, Kentor.AuthServices works the way you want. Even though it comes either as an httpmodule, an mvc controller or an owin middleware, it only interfers with the first requests that make up the actual sign in. All subsequent requests are just passed through and the session cookie mechanism handles the session authentication.

Comment: Thanks Anders.  And thanks for all your effort on the Kentor Authservices.  I have pulled down the project from GITHub.  I have decided to attempt to implement the HTTP Module method of implementation.  I have modified the Web.config but now am unsure which of the massive number of files I need to include within my directory structure.  I think it is just Kentor.AuthServices.HttpModule.  Also can I still use the HTTP Module if I am using a .Net web API with a HTML/JavaScript front end or do I have to use the MVC impelementation?  Sorry for stupid questions still trying to learn.

Comment: This is another question, please post it as one instead of as a comment. Having new questions in comments on Stack Overflow quickly gets messy.